# Params parameter when using optional paramters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, generics, razor

I'm am currently writing overrides to provide own implementations of MVC controls. I would like to work with optional parameters so it saves me the work of writing and maintaining multiple overrides like I solved it now.

Example of my call

```
public static MvcHtmlString MyControlFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html
                                                       , Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression
                                                       , object htmlAttributes = null
                                                       , params Expression<Func<TModel, object>>[] expressions)
```

When working with optional parameters and not providing them all, I need to work with the named parameters. I also know in that case you need to pass an array object to the params parameter in order to work. But it is here I can't figure out how I can do this.

calling the following gives me the following error (CS0826: No best type found for implicitly-typed array):

```
@Html.MyControlFor(x => x.property, expressions: new [] { x=>x.property2, x=>x.property3 });
```

Passing an strong type array doesn't seem to be a solution too because the compiler doesn't recognizes the Expression class. So the following doesn't seem to work

```
@Html.MyControlFor(x => x.property
                 , expressions: new Expression<Func<TModel, object>>[] { x=>x.property2, x=>x.property3 });
```

Does any one have any idea how I can make this work? Or am I doomed to keep working with overrides?

Comment: Include System.Linq? This looks to me like it should work.  I'm wondering if Expression exists somewhere else in the namespace as something totally different.  I'm not that familiar with MVC to know though.

Comment: Your strongly typed version should be worked. At least it compiles with my Visual Studio 2012 without error. You said the compiler doesn't recognize Expression class, did you have "using System.Linq.Expressions;" statements in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you can't add the System.Linq namespace to a razor view is because razor is based on the dynamic type and the System.Linq namespace only contains extension methods. Due the fact the type of a dynamic is only known at runtime, you can't use extension methods on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add using statements to a Razor view like so:

```
@using System.Linq.Expressions
```

Comment: I don't have a reference to System.Linq of System.Linq.Expressions. It seems I can't add it in my view (razor syntax)